# JSS app not finding the layout after Headless Tenant creation when I deserialize items first

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs, sxa-jss

I'm using JSS Next with XM running into Docker and I'm getting a layout not found error, but I don't know where I can validate this.

My scenario is the following, I've some serialized items and I know that when I create a Headless Tenant, some templates like, App Route, Headless Site, are created in the templates/project/ folder, to avoid a conflict of ids, I'm deserializing first and then creating the Tenant so that the folder is merged at the time of dynamic creation, and I believe that is the problem. Because when I only create the Tenant, the layout is found and when I deserialize first and create the Tenant the layout is not found.

I've already rebuilt the indexes, rebuilt the link databases, scanned the database for broken links and nothing. I've already validated the fields in the setting folder that link the folders in templates/project and tried to find the part that JSS run the query to get the Layout, but I didn't find it.

Can someone help me?

Here are some screenshots to put the problem into context.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've solved this issues creating a package of folders, getting all folders that I need to keep the IDs, like template/project, rendering/project and so on. Now I'm installing this package, then creating the Headless Tenant and then running the serialization in this order. But now I'm thinking about how can I keep the Content stuffs ID, because the SXA will create this items dinamically and the ID between environment will be different.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem, here are two things that were checked.

1 - Validate the rootPath and startItem in your App Config, the path must be correct. If necessary, go to showconfig.aspx and check it.

2 - If you create a Tenant and Site using the SXA UI, pay attention to serialize the items created in the template/project and create in the other environments using these templates, to maintain a structure with the same IDs in the other environments, this will allow the item package creation between the environments without conflict.